# Kendo multiselect list option view update - Angular

Tags: angular15, kendo-multiselect

Long story short, I'm programmatically setting the value of a Kendo MultiSelect instance to the ones I want to be selected, like:

```
MultiSelectInstance.value = [selectedValue1, selectedValue2]
```

But doing it that way looks like it does not update the list option view(marking the ones selected as selected)

The way our implementation is done cannot accept the use of ngModel or reactive approach, as they use in their examples:

```
<kendo-label text="T-shirt size:">
        <kendo-multiselect
          [data]="listItems"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedValues"
        ></kendo-multiselect>
      </kendo-label>
```

Which seems to work awesome, unfortunately we are creating a MultiSelect instance on the fly(componentRef) and attaching the view to the ApplicationRef, so no static html and easy way of implementing this is acceptable, aand it looks pretty complex and overkill to implement some kind of class/component that would encapsulate the kendo multiselect in it's template with a ngModel attached to the a property of this class that updating it should do the trick.

Main problem is that I cannot understand what the heck they actually mean with this sentence in their [docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/value-binding/) when updating values using the instance value property:

> Use the value property. If the value is set through the value property, you have to hook up to the valueChange event and manually update the value of the value property.

So if anyone knows how to get the list updated using just the value property of the MultiSelect class, or knows what Kendo team means with the sentence above would be very much appreciate

Thanks again